# How do I setup my project to run integration tests with Spring 3.2.4 version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I'm working on a legacy project that have no tests. We want to add integration tests for our services.
The services communicates with other services and with the database as well.

I could handle to run junit tests so I can mock service calls and database calls to return whatever I want but I'm wondering if it's possible to run an actual integration test where it communicate with the actual dev database and with the other services in the project as well.

The beans are defined in xml files with some placeholders on it. 
I'm looking for a direction on what to look for and if it is possible at all on this spring version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To configure your test can you make first class SwitchCase and extend this in test class.

```
import java.util.Random;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;



@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class SwitchCase{

 *** here you can have tour variables and do @Autowired in yours service

}


public class YoursTestClass  extends SwitchCase{

    @Test
    public void save() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

To do mocks you can use Mockito.

```
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class YouClass {

 @Autowired
 MockMvc mock

 MockHttpServelet request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
 .post("http/....")
 .contentTupe(**pass yout content type **);

 mock.perform(request)
 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated())
 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("id").value(7)
}
```

It is just an example to guide, but it would be good to take a look at the mockito documentation